# Excel - extracting data based on another column value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have 3 column A B C

I need to extract values in column A to another(column E) based on value of C.

if column C is no then extra value in column A
if column A has 2 equal values `111` then check if either of C is yes, if it is yes extract that one.
if both of column C is NO then extract both in list.

```
 A     B    C
123   22    NO
111   21    NO
111   22    YES
222   33    NO
222   34    NO
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  A    B    C
 123   22   NO
 111   21   YES
 222   33   NO
 222   34   NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Your english is not good but do you want to put this in field E:

```
=IF(C1 = "NO",A1,B1)
```

If not exactly, it should at least point you in the right directions.  BTW, you can nest IF statements like this:

```
=IF(C1 = "NO",IF(B1 = "YES",D1,A1),B1)
```

Comment: How can B1 even be `YES` column B has numbers.

Comment: It is an example, something to get you pointed in the right direction. (Teach a man to fish)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- if no duplicates in column A, copy row
- if duplicate in column A, first take the one that is Yes otherwise take all No's

  ```
  Sub LoopRange()
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lCell As Range
    Dim jCell As Range
    Dim rRng As Range
    Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A5")
    Dim rCntr As Integer
    rCntr = 1

    Dim rangelist As String

    'loop through main list
    For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
      Dim duplicate As Boolean
      duplicate = False

    On Error Resume Next
    Set isect = Application.Intersect(Range(rCell.Address), Range(rangelist))
    If isect Is Nothing Then
      ' loop through rest of list to check for duplicates
      For Each lCell In rRng.Cells
          'Check for duplicates
          If lCell.Value = rCell.Value Then
              'Add duplicate row to list
              If duplicate = False Then
                  rangelist = "A" & lCell.row
              Else
                  rangelist = rangelist & "," & "A" & lCell.row
              End If
              duplicate = True
          End If
      Next lCell

      'If a duplicate was found
      If duplicate = True Then
          Dim nRng As Range
          Set nRng = Range(rangelist)
          Dim isNO As Boolean
          isYes = False
          For Each jCell In nRng
              If jCell.Offset(0, 2) = "YES" Then
                  Range(jCell, jCell.Offset(0, 2)).Select
                  Selection.Copy
                  Range("E" & rCntr).Select
                  ActiveSheet.Paste
                  isYes = True
                  rCntr = rCntr + 1
              End If
          Next jCell

          'list all no's
          If isYes = False Then
              For Each jCell In nRng
                  Range(jCell, jCell.Offset(0, 2)).Select
                  Selection.Copy
                  Range("E" & rCntr).Select
                  ActiveSheet.Paste
                  rCntr = rCntr + 1
              Next jCell
          End If
      End If
  End If
   Next rCell
  End Sub
  ```

This is what I get

[image]